# How can I iterate through JSON and output to a UITableViewCell?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to deserialize my JSON and output the values into a UITableViewCell. It looks like it never hits my foreach loop though. I put a breakpoint in and it never hits it and my loadingIndicator continues to spin.

My JSON looks like this: `"theYear":"2012","theMake":"Chevrolet/GMC","theModel":"Avalanche 1500 4WD","theEngine":"5.3L V-8","theTowLimit":"5000","notes":"3.08 axle ratio "`

**Code**:

```
string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TowInfo> (result);

//theTopInfo.Text = parsed.theYear + " " + parsed.theMake + " " + parsed.theModel;

foreach (var item in parsed.data) {

   Console.WriteLine(item.theEngine + " " + item.theTowLimit + " " + item.notes);

}

public class TowInfo
{
    public List<TowRatings> data { get; set;}

}

public class TowRatings
{
    public string theYear { get; set; }
    public string theMake { get; set; }
    public string theModel { get; set; }
    public string theEngine { get; set; }
    public string theTowLimit { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: have you verified that your json is being deserialized correctly?  Does the json data contain a top level "data" element?  Or is it just an array of TowRatings?

Comment: That's not valid Jason without brackets around it, and even if it has them it is one object so you cannot loop over one object. If deserialization is working you want simply parsed.theEngine, etc.

Comment: when i add it to a `List<>`, it doesn't hit the break point, but when i just set it to `var = parsed` it does hit it. `List< TowInfo > parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List< TowInfo >> (result);`